# How to check whether a value is a numeric value in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

When someone enters a value (Year), I want to validate the value. I.e., I want to check whether the value is a numeric. I am new to Prolog. Can you help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just write down - in Prolog - the rules that - under your judgment - define what a valid year must be. For example

```
valid_year(Y) :-
  integer(Y), Y > 0, Y =< 2014.
```

You can see from this snippet that your question is largely unspecified: what about future ? and far past ? What about other calendar systems (there are plenty) ?

In SWI-Prolog, there is extensive support for [time and date](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=datimepreds), but I feel it is definitely beyond your current requirements...